# Can anyone simplify this sentence?

Tags: sentence-meaning

This is the whole paragraph and the bolded sentence is the sentence that makes me confused:

> Logic usually deals with terms that are either true or false. Fuzzy logic is a branch
>   of logic that deals with terms that can have any intermediate value between true and
>   false. Say that true is 1 and that false is 0. Rather than dealing with the two-element
>   set {0,1}, fuzzy logic deals with the infinite interval [0,1] of all real numbers
>   between 0 and 1. With this we can give different values in different cases. Telly
>   Savalas and Yul Brynner are both totally bald and hence would have the value 0.
>   People with full heads of hair would get a 1. People in the middle will get middle
>   values. 0.1 means almost bald, while 0.5 is halfway there. Someone might get the
>   value of 0.7235. **With these different values set up, researchers have gone on to
>   develop different operations similar to AND and OR to work in this logic.**
>
> Source: The Outer Limits of Reason: What Science, Mathematics, and Logic Cannot Tell Us by Noson S. Yanofsky

My problem is with the bold sentence; especially, "to work in this logic". Does it mean that researchers developed different operations similar to AND and OR and did make them work in this branch of logic" or does it mean that " researchers developed different operations similar to AND and OR so researchers can work in this branch of logic" or something else?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So, the question is did the researchers create the operations with

1 the purpose of having the operations work in fuzzy logic
or
2 the purpose of being able to use the operations in fuzzy logic themselves.

It can be read either way, but it's a difference that has no effect.